# ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm plotting with ListPointPlot3D, but the plot is fuzzy. I don't understand why. Can you help?

```
Z={{-2 Sqrt[2], -4 Sqrt[2], 4 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2], -2 Sqrt[2], 0, 
  0, -2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 Sqrt[2], 0, 
  2 Sqrt[2], -2 Sqrt[2], 0}, {-4, 0, 0, 0, 4, -4, -4, 0, 4, -4, -2, 2,
   4, 0, 4, -4, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 0, -4, 0, 4, 2, 4, 0, -4, 4, -4, -4, 
  4, -2, 0, -4, 4}}  
 ListPointPlot3D[Z]
Y = (Z . Transpose[Z]) // MatrixForm  
CharacteristicPolynomial[Y/8, \[Lambda]]  
6800 - 1097 \[Lambda] + 58 \[Lambda]^2 - \[Lambda]^3  
Solve[6800 - 1097 \[Lambda] + 58 \[Lambda]^2 - \[Lambda]^3 == 
  0, \[Lambda]]  
{{\[Lambda] -> 16}, {\[Lambda] -> 17}, {\[Lambda] -> 25}}  
Eigenvectors[Y]  
a1 = {0, -1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]};  
a2 = {0, 1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]};  
a3 = {1, 0, 0};  
P = Transpose[Z]  
c = Show[ListPointPlot3D[P, Filling -> Axis],   
  Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 4 a1}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 4 a2}],  
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 4 a3}]}]]    
Show[c, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}, Axes -> {True, True, False}]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please upload your Mathematica code in  copy-paste-able form (not as an image) so that forum participants can experiment with it and assist you further. Also run `$Version` to include version and provide OS information.

Comment: It's likely that you want `(Y = Z . Transpose[Z]) // MatrixForm` so the value `Z . Transpose[Z]` gets stored in `Y` rather than a formatted non-computable output.

Comment: @MarcoB Is that why the graph is fuzzy?

Comment: @Murad the graph is not fuzzy in my version, unfortunately, so I can't tell.